# How do I hide/disable custom taxonomies (meta box) when a specific category is selected?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently using a plugin "CPT UI" to create a custom taxonomy, it is display well on the front-end product page (using a multi-vendor plugin, wcfm), and also on the admin backend add product page of course.

I was trying to hide the custom taxonomy based on the product category that the product is currently under, but not sure how to do it.

Tried several options, and play around with if statement, like

if (is_product() && has_term...

No such luck.

Here are the code that I tried:

```
function ev_unregister_taxonomy(){
if (is_product() && has_term( 'Bike Parts', 'product_cat' )){
    register_taxonomy('brand', array());
   }
}

add_action('init', 'ev_unregister_taxonomy');
```

Expecting to have for example, when a product has "Gear" category selected, then this taxonomy "Brand" should disappear.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with the php files if you don't have enough knowldge , your can use jquery to hide anything from the website